# Assign value in "let" constant variable , which is inside cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

My application has a third party "Mapbox", which is imported through pod.

Now I want to change the value with my API response. But wnable to assign as it is a "let" constant.

So I have created a "Extenstion" file of that class with below computed property to set the value.

```
extension RouteStep {
   var maneuverLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
       get
       {
           return self.maneuverLocation
       }
       set
       {
           self.maneuverLocation = newValue
       }
    }
}
```

I am passing the value like this :

```
 let step : RouteStep = RouteStep.init(json: jsonObject)
    step.maneuverLocation = maneuverLocation
```

but it gives me error of infinity type as in[image] following image

Comment: Can you please little bit more descriptive. what I can write there?

Comment: that seem like an infinite loop to me... and based on your `extension`, it is an infinite loop indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Its obvious why you are stuck at an infinite loop, but even if somehow you were able to resolve that, the issue here is that Swift extensions does not support stored properties.

You can have a computed property but not stored properties, not in a straightforward way anyway.

If RouteStep is derived from Obj-C runtime then you can use associated properties as a solution. This [post](https://marcosantadev.com/stored-properties-swift-extensions/) explains how to perform that.

I guess, if you can explain what you mean by this and what do you want to actually achieve, then the community can help you better.

> Now I want to change the value with my API response. But wnable to
>   assign as it is a "let" constant.

**EDIT**: (After OP explained more about the problem)

If `maneuverLocation` variable is declared as let inside SDK, there is no way you can change it in an extension. May be you can subclass the RouteStep if it is a class and provide an init and if its a value type, I guess you can add convenience init inside its extension. Once the instance is created, there is no way to change the value inside the let variable. It has to be done inside an init.

Comment: So is there any other solution to set my values in the same. I need it to store

Comment: Awesome Obj-C runtime solution!

Comment: @Puneet from my API response , i am getting "maneuverLocation" and I want to replace the same with SDK.

Comment: @Myaaoonn : Are you trying to create a variable with the same name in your extension which is already declared inside mapbox framework as a constant?

Comment: Yes I have to set the value of that variable which is in mapbox framework . but in frame work that is "let" assigned.